# Trying to create an array of points to plot. How do you add more points to the array?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a midpoint function that returns the total area under a curve and the points needed to plot each of the rectangles. I have this code but am unsure how to add more points into an array correctly.

```
for index = 1:N
        x = [lines(index)-.5*dx(index), lines(index)-.5*dx(index), lines(index+1)-.5*dx(index), lines(index+1)-.5*dx(index)];
        y = [0 f(index) f(index) 0];
        ****points = [x;y] + points;
```

The expected results would be all the points needed to graph N number of rectangles at their midpoint. Instead it gives me an error.

Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in midpoint (line 13)
            points = [x;y] + points;

Comment: The correct way would be to preallocate a `2 x N` array and use `index` to decide which column of the array to assign the new values to.

Answer (score 0):

More clean and short without for loops:

```
clear

%% setup
f=@(x) sin(x)+x.^2; %function
x0=-pi; x1=pi; %range
N=20; %num of mid points

%% calculations
xs=linspace(x0,x1,N+1); %rectangles xs
xm=(xs(1:end-1)+xs(2:end))/2; %N mid points
ym=f(xm); %value at midpoint
midpoint_area=sum(ym)*(x1-x0)/N;

%% print results
trapezoid_area=trapz(xm,ym); %compare to trapezoid matlab function
fprintf('midpoint_area=%.2f, trapezoid_area=%.2f\n',midpoint_area,trapezoid_area)

%% plots
figure(1); cla; 
fplot(f,[x0,x1]); 
hold on;
xrects=[xs(1),repelem(xs(2:end-1),2),xs(end)] ; %for ploting. each xs used for 2 mid points values
yrects=repelem(ym,2);
stem(xrects,yrects,'Color','black','Marker','none') %plot rectangles
plot(xrects,yrects,'Color','black') %plot rectangles
if N<40
    plot(xm,ym,'Og') %midpoint
    text(xm,ym,strcat('\leftarrow',sprintfc('[%.1f',xm),sprintfc(',%.1f] ',ym)))
end
```